# Lighting for indoor citrus to produce full fruit

Tags: fruit-trees, indoors, fruits, citrus, light

I'm getting a few different citrus trees I'd like to grow against the wall in my living room. I currently have a hydroponic veggie setup so I'm not a total beginner.

I was wondering what lighting I could use for a 3x6 ft area to get the plants to fully fruit?

It sounds like a few hanging LEDs with cone fixtures would be my best bet, but I have no idea what lights would be strong enough.

I also don't know what fixtures I could use that would have a strong enough socket. Fixtures are a little important since I don't want people to become accidentally blinded when looking around the room.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Cole, what's your price point?   This will make the largest impact on what you can get.   I think you should also post a picture of the style of fixture that is appropriate for you.   What do you mean by, 'strong enough socket'?

Comment: @GardenGems I'm not sure if all light fixtures can support a LED grow light, so that's what I was referring to as "strong enough".

I was thinking a simple barn light or cone fixture similar to this: https://tinyurl.com/vn8pmfq

Comment: what you are saying is you want a LED grow light that fits a E22/27 socket.   They do make them.  No single light/fixture is going to a 18sqft area.   Being you want a cone shape, they are meant to light only one plant.    You will need a seperate one for each plant.   You are better off getting a different style that will cover a largers area.   There are not many fixtures that will cover that amount of area.

Comment: @GardenGems Thank you for explaining the proper lighting verbiage I was looking for, that helps a lot.

Since I will be growing trees I figured on high power LED in a standard light socket with a cone fixtured would be ideal for the aethetic purposes as well as the simplictiy of hanging. 

However if I will struggle to find a powerful enough bulb then I may go for the larger lights you suggested.

Comment: Do you still have any questions?  If not I will move my comments to the answer.  You can mark it correct if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what type of light you finally decide to use, you must buy a full spectrum white light.  Do not buy any coloured lights.  Studies show that white light, which includes Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet light.  All the lights of the spectrum.  It may also include some IR & UV as well.   This will ensure you get good flowering, growth of the plant, growth of the fruit, including ripening of the fruit, overall health of the plant.

If you were growing a little cannabis, a seasonal crop perhaps you could get away with some kind of Red/Blue light, but you are not growing a seasonal, you are growing an all seasonal crop.  Yours from flower to fruit takes the full year.  You need the best spectrum as well as duration of light.

Normally I would advice you to put your light on 16-18 hours during the growing season and 12-14 during the rest period, but citrus are an all season grower, so you will need your light to be on for 16-18 hours year round.   It does not come from a region of the world with a dormant season.  If it does, it is very short.

It's the amount of light and the full spectrum of light that are the most important.  I think you are correct with getting away with a 200-400 watt light.  You do not want to go lower and if you have a good quality light you will not need any stronger.

Watt is not what they use to measure the best lights.  They use PAR and other measurements.  Most of the best lights and some of the cheap lights have a reviews on Youtube.  Take time to review these videos, some of the reviewers have great equipment for measure the quality of a light.  They may not have your  Carnegie Pendant LED Grow Light, but they do have pendant/spotlight lamps reviews on Youtube.

As I mentioned in my comments, 'No single light/fixture is going to a 18sqft area. Being you want a cone shape, they are meant to light only one plant. You will need a separate one for each plant. You are better off getting a different style that will cover a larger area. There are not many fixtures that will cover that amount of area'

I hope this helped shed some light on your question.